# Pass a value to loadURL - Android

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to pass a value to the URL mentioned in webView.loadUrl? something like this??

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#value="+value);
```

or is there any way to pass a Java String value to the Javascript function in loadURL?

Comment: So you want to pass a value to the page at your given URL which should then (on this page) be used with JavaScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution.. posting it here for the sake of others :)

I added the following snippet of code in my Activity class which solved the problem,

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
                {  
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:callMe(\""+data_val+"\")");

                }  
            });
```

Thanks all :)

Comment: can you please tell how to accept and use that data_val variable on html side

Comment: Not bad, but it's still only half of the solution. Need to figure how to handle the data once it arrives at the JavaScript layer.

Comment: This works, but just to clarify your answer: in your code, `callMe` should be a function inside the javascript of the page to handle `data_val`.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Yes.. you are right. `callMe` is a function with a single argument to handle `data_val`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [GET-Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to do so. Note that the maximum length of a URL is 256 chars!

After you supplied your arguments that way, you can use JavaScript to read them (by cutting them out of the URL). Here is a [Code-Snipped](http://snipplr.com/view/799/get-url-variables/) and [an article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. Below is the code which is working

```
String s = "http://10.0.2.2/myhtml/add.php?bc=" + bc;   
myWebView.loadUrl(s);
```