# loadUrl for CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I just want to modify this part of code:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/ARview.html");
final String testValue = "test value";
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){   
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:testData('" + testValue + "')");
    }           
});
```

... which consists to pass data to the WebView into a version for a CordovaWebView.
When I execute this part of code (with webView a WebView object), everything's fine, it's perfectly working.
But when I change "webView" by a CordovaWebView object, it crashes.

How can I handle this?

Thank you!

Note1: if I remove the "setWebViewClient" part from the code, and I use a CordovaWebView object as webView, everything's working fine. Actually I just want to know how to pass data to a CordovaWebView.

Note2: this part of code is taken from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368871/pass-a-value-to-loadurl-android)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my solution by myself (with some research on the net):

Here is the final code:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/ARview.html");
final String testValue = "test value";
webView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView) {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:testData(" + testValue + ")");
    }
});
```

I precise once again that "webView" here is a CordovaWebView object. And now it's working...